# Is there a way to forecast sales for multiple products across multiple stores?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, arima, facebook-prophet

My Data is in this format(Both Multiple and Multivariate Timeseries)

[image]

I need to predict number of units sold is gonna be for every product across different stores(Store 1,Store 2,Store 3) using time-series model.

I have scaled down the number for easeness.

I am fairly new to Time Series. Please help me with the approach I need to take to solve this problem

Reproducible Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '02-01-2020', '02-01-2020', '03-01-2020'], 
'SKU': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
'Store1': [10, 12, 11, 14, 12, 15],
'Store2': [20, 12, 19, 17, 17, 13],
'Store3': [11, 17, 17, 11, 18, 17]})
```

Comment: Could you be more specific. Are you saying given store 1,2,3 sell item SKU-1 at prices 10,20,11, what is the most likely value that store 4 sells item SKU-1? That isn't time-series.

Comment: These are the units that were sold. for the SKUs 1 and 2 across stores 1-3. I need to predict the future units to be sold in these 3 stores

Comment: Yes, but my question isn't answered, what are you trying to predict?

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible data example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples?noredirect=1&lq=1). [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be downvoted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: Ah, I see I miss understood, let me rephrase the question, are you tying to predict the number of units sold at store 4, given the number of units sold at store 1,2,3?

Comment: No. I am trying to predict the number of units sold at stores 1,2,3 for future dates(Based on historic date) for the SKU 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

You could try using deep learning, boosting models, among others
For traditional time series you'd need to train one model for each combination product-store

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your data and problem is a good fit for hierarchical forecasting and/or using a complex LSTM.

Nixtla has a nice package that tackles hierarchical forecasting: https://nixtlaverse.nixtla.io/hierarchicalforecast/index.html

Also these are some good Q&As related to your question:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412276/how-to-handle-many-times-series-simultaneously
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389291/strategies-for-time-series-forecasting-for-2000-different-products